# Learning sources for UWP (Universal windows platform)

Tags: win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10-universal

Can you give me some good learning sources for UWP App development?
Currently I use the ["Windows 10 development for absolute beginners"](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-10-development-for-absolute-beginners) series on channel9. But it's not going in the depth.
I'd like to learn more about the anatomy of UWP apps and also some more advanced topics.

Comment: Take a look at the Microsoft Virtual Academy courses. Those will help. Everything else is learning by doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend looking at [MVA courses](https://mva.microsoft.com) on the topics and level you need.

[This one](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/a-developers-guide-to-windows-10-12618?l=IV8HDBpRB_9005095281) is a very comprehensive course. You can pick the modules of your interest - just note that it was updated in Aug 2015 and some things might have changed in the meantime. There are plenty of other resources that you can look at after that.

Comment: They are not teaching in depth. Learning only XAML Controls and data binding is not enough to understand this huge and awesome platform.

Answer (score 2):

Please check below sources:

1. First one is official UWP guideline how to create apps. You can find here many different descriptions how to implement design of your app. Below you can download it as a PDF file:

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=626098

2. Second source can be official MSDN website with samples and descriptions related to Universal Windows 10 Apps:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/design

3. If you would like to create first simple Universal Windows 10 App I also recommend my blog where you can find many different articles connected with UWP:

https://mobileprogrammerblog.wordpress.com/2015/08/23/first-windows-10-universal-application-jump-start/

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Also check [Windows-universal-samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples) from github. You can find code samples for everything you want to do with the platform straight from Microsoft.